# MPlayer Plays Video too Fast When "pcm_u8" Audio Codec Used

Tags: mplayer, codec

Running **SMPlayer** as my **MPlayer** (version svn 34540 (Debian Wheezy)) front end.

I have two **.avi** video files.  Both are identical to each other except for the audio codecs used (FYI, both use the "**mpeg4 (Simple Profile)**" *video* codec).  One file uses the "**pcm_u8**" audio codec and one uses the "**adpcm_im_wav**" audio codec.  Note that the codec nomenclatures reported here are those reported by the `avprobe` command.

**SMPlayer** (and **MPlayer**) play the video file with said "**adpcm_im_wav**" audio codec just fine.  However, when these players are used to play the video file with said "**pcm_u8**" audio codec, the video track plays faster than does the audio track.  Note that said problem is not a bias-related problem, it is a *rate*-related problem...

It is interesting to note that both videos play fine using **Parole** (v. 0.2.0.2 (Debian Squeeze)).  FYI, Parole is a front end for the **GStreamer** framework.

Any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Comment: You filed a bug report?

Comment: @dirkt, no, sadly.  Two reasons:  First is that I lack to confidence to do so and second is that my version of MPlayer is an old one (comes with Debian 7 (Wheezy)).  I did see vague references to a bug that may apply to my issue, though, during the process of researching this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround for the above-stated problem, I use the following switch for **MPlayer**:

`-fps 26.97`

This value was arrived at via trial and error.  The subject video plays fine when said switch is utilized.

However, it may be interesting to note that, after merging two of these "problem" **avi** files (using `avimerge` utilizing the `-c` switch), I had to use an `fps` setting of **32.97** in order to get good playback with **MPlayer**.

Answer (score 2):

There is one more option to try:

```
mplayer -autosync 30 -mc 2.0
```

These options will instruct `mplayer` to use A/V correction algorithm for video processing in pretty free way without strict limitations. Worked pretty good for me, when I had similar issue.